# Webpack haml-jsx loader problems

Tags: webpack, haml, webpack-4

I am trying to set-up my webpack bundling so that I might be able to use haml for templating instead of jsx. So this is what i did for my loaders section of my webpack config:

```
use:[
      {
         loader:"babel-loader",
         options:{
            presets: ['@babel/preset-env'],
            plugins: [require('@babel/plugin-syntax-jsx')]
         }
      },
      {
        loader:"haml-jsx-loader"
      }
]
```

so the problem presents itself when webpack goes to load the .haml template. I get this error: "module parse failed: unexpected token. you may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.

here is the full config for debugging purposes:

```
const path = require('path');
module.exports = {
    entry:path.resolve(__dirname,"index.js"),
    module:{
        rules:[
            {
                test:/\.haml$/,
                use:[
                    {
                        loader:"babel-loader",
                        options:{
                            presets: ['@babel/preset-env'],
                            plugins: [require('@babel/plugin-syntax-jsx')]
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        loader:"haml-jsx-loader"
                    }
                ]   
            },
        ]
    },
    output: {
        filename:"bundle.js",
        path: path.resolve(__dirname,"/distro")
    },
};
```

Comment: Try changing `haml-jsx-loader` to `haml-jsx`.

Comment: I tried that but I seem to be still getting the same error.                        ```ERROR in ./index.js 2:68
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (2:68)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| const path = require('path');
> let toBeHTML = require(path.resolve(__dirname,"/haml/template.haml");```